# max-width 50% for td

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>td1td1td1td1 td1td1td1td1td1td1td1td1td1td1td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td{
    border:black thin solid;
    max-width:50%;
}
table{
    width:100%
}
```

I want to set the max width of the `td` to `50%`, but it isn’t working for me ...
Hope someone could help on this.

Please view the output on: http://jsfiddle.net/38bf2/

**P.S.**
I already try to view the result via Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add `table-layout:fixed;`. Change your CSS on the table to:

```
table{
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/38bf2/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `max-width` try `width:50%;`

Comment: width and max-width is not the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
td{
    border:black thin solid;
    max-width:50%;
    width:50%;
}
table{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: then, max-width is useless